# Why doesn't my ruby loop create N threads?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, loops

I'm playing around with ruby at the moment, and I'm interested in using multiple threads; n to be exact.

However, my program gets stuck on running the first thread to completion instead of starting the rest of the threads.

I've look around on the web for some assistance but found nothing that really helped.

```rb
numberThreads = 5

puts "Number of threads: " + numberThreads.to_s 

for i in 1..numberThreads do

    threads << Thread.new{
        function(x, y)
    }

end

threads.each { |thr| thr.join }
```

I'm looking to have all n threads (in this case 5) run the function simultaneously.

Comment: Second sentence: https://apidock.com/ruby/Thread/join But you'll likely want to read docs like https://www.toptal.com/ruby/ruby-concurrency-and-parallelism-a-practical-primer, https://dev.to/enether/working-with-multithreaded-ruby-part-i-cj3, https://engineering.universe.com/introduction-to-concurrency-models-with-ruby-part-i-550d0dbb970, etc.

Comment: Since your example is incomplete, we have no clue what the problem is. Please make [example] that accurately shows your problem.

Comment: @Amadan the issue is [`Thread#join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Thread.html#method-i-join) that synchronizes execution.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: I cannot see anything there that would prevent other threads running while threads[0] is being waited upon. Once thread[0] completes, again nothing prevents threads[x] for x>1 to run while thread[1] is being waited on. This just looks like a common pattern, with no discernable reason why other threads would block, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: Proof that this runs in parallel, simultaneously (with minimal modifications to make it execute): https://repl.it/repls/FluffyShadyToolbox . The example would execute in 25 seconds if it was serial, but it completes in 5 seconds (with start and end of each thread happening at roughly the same time).

Comment: @Amadan oh, indeed. For some reason, I thought one should explicitly call `Thread#pass` to pass the control to the awaiting thread.